# I am confused with the wording of the code

Tags: java

I read source code of JDK and confused with the wording of the code.  The method of code mean that returns a string representation of the contents of the specified array.

eg:  int[] a = { 0,1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9 };
     return  :  [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]

JDK version

```
 public static String toString(int[] a) {
    if (a == null)
        return "null";
   int iMax = a.length - 1;
   if (iMax == -1)
        return "[]";

    StringBuilder b = new StringBuilder();
    b.append('[');
    for (int i = 0; ; i++) {
        b.append(a[i]);
        if (i == iMax)
            return b.append(']').toString();
        b.append(", ");
    }
}
```

My questions:
 1, Why not put the if condition  on the outside of the for loop
code:

```
 //the follow code efficiency may be better or not
 for (int i = 0; i< iMax; i++) {
        b.append(a[i]);
        b.append(", ");
    }
 return  b.append(a[iMax]).append(']').toString();
```

2, `StringBuilder` the  `append`  method, if the parameter is  the bracket, the method use the char parameter and not the String , I deep into the  `append` methods ,  the`append(char c)` approach appears to high efficiency, but I'm not sure

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you code can be further optimized/refactored like this:

```
public static String toString(int[] a) {
    if (a == null)
        return "null";
    StringBuilder b = new StringBuilder("[");
    int iMax = a.length - 1;
    if (iMax == -1)
         return b.append(']').toString();;
    for (int i = 0; i < iMax; i++)
        b.append(a[i]).append(", ");
    return b.append(a[iMax]).append(']').toString();
}
```

Comment: No, now you don't have an optimized code path for the empty-array case.

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik: Would you pls care to explain your comment?

Comment: The original code involves no `StringBuilder` in the empty-array case. The performance advantage of that is obvious.

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik: And how about code repetitions? I would refactor above code even further to have only single return with only single place to attach `[` and `]`.

Comment: Optimization and code elegance are often at odds. The implementations of JDK classes prefer performance over LOC.

Answer (score 0):

1. Your code compares numbers by `<` (less-than) which will never perform better than the equals comparison (`==`), and it may perform worse. So the JDK version is more carefully optimized and thought-through.
2. Yes, it's more efficient to use a primitve arg wherever applicable. No heap allocation, no pointer derefs (avoids possible cache misses and page faults).

Comment: "Your code uses less-than comparison which can only be less performant than the equals comparison" - what does that mean?

Comment: I know what you are saying, but I don't understand why you are saying it!  Why is `<` less efficient than `==`?

Comment: @OliCharlesworth think of assembly-level implementation. `==` means comparing bit-for-bit; `<` means a `sub` followed by a sign-test. **At best** they are the same, and there's a good chance `<` is less performant.

Comment: On most platforms, these will be identical cost.  In fact, I can't think off-hand of an instruction set where they would be different.  And even if there *was* a difference, I would expect the JVM/JIT to do the "right thing".

Comment: @OliCharlesworth So you've given arguments that they are the same most of the time. No claim was made that there **will** be a difference in performance.

Comment: That's true, but equally, you've given no evidence that they will ever be different, so I'm not sure it's relevant to your answer.  I struggle to believe that this is the reason that the code was written the way it was.

Comment: BTW @OliCharlesworth There are plenty of examples of CPU's where there is a definite difference: Z80, Intel 8086, Motorola 68000... Those lines were written about 1995, the world was different back then. An experienced coder of that time probably had this difference already in his bones.

Comment: The _only_ way to prove claims like this is to actually go and perform benchmarks.  Get hard numbers to back up your claims.

Comment: @LouisWasserman The hypothesis here involves the motivations of the author of those lines. It's unprovable by default, which doesn't automatically exclude it from thought.

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik: 8086?  It has `JE`, `JGE`, `JL` etc.

Comment: @OliCharlesworth Did you find a timing table for the instructions? Back in those days there was virtually no instruction that executed in a single cycle.

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik: That's true, I didn't.  But all the conditional branches are based on simple tests of status flags; I would imagine (although I haven't looked it up) that these would all have equivalent latencies.

Comment: @OliCharlesworth Yes, but without a dedicated single-purpose logic module, performing binary arithmetic is nowhere near the same as just comparing two registers bitwise. When all you have is on the order of 10k transistors, there's no room for such monsters.

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik: All the relevant flags are set by the `CMP` instruction (on x86, at least).

Comment: @OliCharlesworth To implement equals, you don't bother with CMP, but use XOR. I even kind of remember such advice from 20 years ago when I played with 8086 as a kid: avoid CMP when you can as it's costly. Memory fades, so don't take my word for it.

Comment: @OliCharlesworth For posterity, I found a [PDF documenting 8086 timings](http://www.oocities.org/mc_introtocomputers/Instruction_Timing.PDF). Both XOR and CMP (reg -> reg, I think that's of interest here) cost 3 cycles. So no difference after all.

Answer (score 0):

1. You have to write the "if" condition inside the "for" loop, cause the structure of "for" loop is :

   ```
     for(initialization, test condition, modifier expression)

    eg: for(int i=0 ; i<10 ; i++)
   ```

   As in the above example for (int i = 0; ; i++) has no test condition, it must be written inside the "for" loop, else it will keep iterating..ie. infinite loop.
2. Here the method  public static String toString(int[] a)  has a return type of String, so its easier to convert it in to string format using toString(), now if it was "char" then it was to be first converted to Wrapper object "Character", then we can apply toString() to it...its tedious.... but can be done...

Answer (score -1):

1.) If you put the if condition after the loop it will add a comma to the end of the string before going out of the loop. Resulting in "[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9,]". Note the final comma after 9. This is the simplest way to get the job done.

2.) StringBuilder is used when you don't want to put a lot of Strings in the String pool which won't get cleaned out. But the honest answer is I'm not sure!